# Using DataTables in role of DTOs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dto

is there no sense in using DataTables as DTOs?
Currently In my MVC project, I'm using my own DAL which it's methods return DataTables also there is ViewModel per views.
so to present data to View there are these steps:

1. DAL returns a DataTable.
2. the result is mapped to a DTO with AutoMapper.
3. the DTO will be mapped to ViewModel with AutoMapper.

if we omit step 2 and map DataTables directly to ViewModels then we gain less code and perhaps even more performance.
so It is practical if we use DataTables instead of DTOs classes?
Could you tell me what reason do you have for your answer?

Comment: Returning DTO/POCO classes from DAL and converting them into specific ViewModel in controller is preferred way. What make sense or not, depends a lot on project need/ROI/etc, you are the best person to judge.

Comment: yes, I'm agree with you this way is practical,but it's my feeling the application does sth more for no reason,why the traditional data tables couldn't act as DTOs?what is it's pros and cons?

Comment: Good questions to add into your original post.

Comment: DataTable objects are very flexible. But DataTable objects are also very inefficient. If you have no specific reason to use DataTables (such as to support your legacy application) and you are looking for the best performance, you should use DTOs. Keep in mind, LINQ provides a lot of additional functionality for DTOs that was previously only available using DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the DTOs? DTOs are data **transfer** objects, usually meaning objects which carry data between processes. If you're not doing any inter-process communication, you likely don't have a need for this.

Omitting step 2 will result in less code, and with your viewmodel in between you already have decoupling from your data structure. From what I can tell in your question: **omit it.**

**Edit**

From your updates, it's still hard to tell why you need DTOs.

I'd like to prevent this from becoming an "it depends"-answer, but without specifics it's hard to give you a definitive answer. My answer to your question boils down to this:

**Don't introduce concepts like DTOs if you don't need them.**

But whether or not you need them is hard to decide without the full context:

- What's the complexity of your application and domain?
- Why does your DAL return DataTables?

You mention combining Domain Models into a DTO: are you likely to reuse the same combination logic for multiple scenarios?

If you **are** reusing the same combination logic, then it might make sense to put it behind some kind of Service/Facade and expose what you'd call a DTO. On the other hand: if your application is 100% really simple, throw-away code: just put everything in your controllers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: we need DTOs or their concepts because in most of cases we fetch some data that they are a combination of some our Domain Models (like join tables in DB) so here is where DTOs come into scene.I agree with you if I omit step 2 it'll result less code but I want know more about it's side effect and more reasonable reasons.

Comment: Your original question only mentions DataTables -> DTO -> ViewModel. Could you update the question so it better reflects your problem? It's hard to answer "should I do this?" questions without enough context.

Comment: Done!
I hope it helps :)

Comment: tnx for your description. about complexity I should say my application has lowest level of data entry by user and it's focus is on presentation of data which being gathered automaticly by the database. my DAL or in my real case ReadModel returns DataTable because I dont use any ORM I make my own DAO and it fills a DataTable,I'm stuck here,whether my ReadModel's methods return a generic list of DTO and I accept another mapping in controlers or return a DataTable in a direct way and have one mapping only in the controllers.